# Adding SKScene to UIViewController gives me errors

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

**What I want**

An infinite background that randomly adds objects (in my cases little stars) to the middle of the screen. Then those objects needs to move out of the screen with a certain speed. This way I want to give the user the feeling they are moving "into space", seeing stars they are passing.

**What I have**

A single view application with a UIViewController class.

**Problem**

I think the right way is to add a SKScene which will do the task I want. However, adding the SKScene class next to UIViewController gives me an error: "multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'SKScene'". I need to add the SKScene to an existence UIViewController, in order to call some important functions. When searching for this on Stackoverflow I came across this: [SKScene in UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439734/skscene-in-uiviewcontroller) But I can not call certain functions like "override func update(current time: CFTimeInterval){}", because the answer doesn't show how to implement the SKScene class. This answer deletes the whole UIViewController class: [Adding an SKScene to a UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156546/adding-an-skscene-to-a-uiviewcontroller). The other answers are not helping me.

**Question**

What is the correct way of adding a SKScene class to an existence UIViewController class, so I can accomplish what I want?

Edit: Came across this on 9gag and its exactly what I want: http://9gag.com/gag/aWmZAPZ Those stars are coming from left top, the respawning should be in the middle of the screen at my app.

Comment: As the answer to the question of your link explains, you cannot directly add an SKScene to a UIView, **SKScene isn't a view at all**, to display it you must first add it to an SKView.

Comment: Ok, but how about adding a SKView to an existing uiviewcontroller? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, it's possible. Instead of directly add `SKScene` to `UIViewController`, you need to warp `SKScene` by `SKView` first, and then add `SKView` to `UIViewController`

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure the view.
        // Core:- convert the base view/UIView of UIViewController to SKView
        let rootView = self.view as! SKView
        //            skView.showsFPS = true
        //            skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        rootView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        rootView.frameInterval = 1

        //init your SKScene
        let rootMenuScene = YourScene(size: rootView.bounds.size)
        rootMenuScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill

        //warp in SKView
        rootView.presentScene(rootMenuScene) 
    }
    ...

}
```